# How do I stop a loop made with (Handler and postAtTime) from a different activity, the one that created it?

Tags: android

I had a method that makes me a continuous loop with postAtTime every x seconds using (Handler), except that this method is placed in an activity A, when going into the activity B and then return to A for pressing stop button  for finsih loop, I can not stop it with `mHandler.removeCallbacks (..)` I am attaching here the method

Button Start:

```
mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
```

Loop:

```
private  Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ok!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
      }
   };
```

Button Stop:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```

Comment: Please don't remove the text of your question after it has been answered. All questions posted on Stackoverflow are kept for future reference, in the hope it will help future visitors and users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// In your handler
SharedPreferences sp = context.getPreferences();
boolean loop = sp.getBoolean("should_loop_ad_infinatium", false);
if (loop) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
```

from another activity

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getPreferences();
Editor e = sp.edit();
e.putBoolean("should_loop_ad_infinatium", false);
e.commit();
```

Comment: thanks, but do you think I can use this same method to stop the loop in the same activity where it was created, or use your code "from another activity" in the stop button of the activity A? after passing through an other activity (B). how to initialize context?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to stop it from the Activity that created it, this should work. If its not, something else is wrong.

Where are you assigning mHandler? If its in onResume, then you're trying to remove the callbacks from a different Handler instance.

Are you returning to the same instance of Activity A from Activity B, or a new one?